# Is it possible to save all documents once again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering, is there any operation in rails console that does something like below ??

```
a = Article.all
foreach a as article
    article.save
end
```

Comment: You want to read every article out and save it without making changes?  Could you be more specific about why you need to save everything at once?  Also, you could just run your code sample from the console.

Comment: Yes thats what I want to do. I am using mongoid. I am trying to set some for specific field which just got added. By merely saving the document, the field will have value that I define.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, I've got an Article model too and just tried it in rails console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > Article.all.each(&:save) 
=> [#<Article id: ...
```

So what did that accomplish?